# Prolog, error with exclusive OR

Tags: prolog

i am new to prolog, and i want to make a simple expert system that uses prepositions, and i am struggling to use exclusive OR. Here is my program so far:

```
/*facts*/
a.
b.
c.

/*rules*/
e :- c.
d :- a, \+e.
f :- xor(b, d). /*here is where it gives me an error*/

/*query*/
?- f.

/*error*/
ERROR: f/0: Undefined procedure: (xor)/2
  Exception: (8) b xor d ? no debug
?-
```

Comment: I suggest you add the error you get, so people can assist you

Comment: just added the error on the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the better way to solve your problem, but anyway...

```
?- X is 1 xor 0.
X = 1.

?- X is 1 xor 1.
X = 0.
```

so

```
:- meta_predicate xor(0,0).

% reify arguments and apply usual boolean
xor(A, B) :-
  ( call(A) -> X=1 ; X=0 ),
  ( call(B) -> Y=1 ; Y=0 ),
  1 is X xor Y.
```

and now

```
?- xor(true,false).
true.

?- xor(true,true).
false.

?- xor(true,1 is 7-6).
false.
```

Comment: thanks a lot i now got it, @coder explained it in a basic way, i am not working on understanding calls and exit maybe i will understand yours fully

Comment: `xor` is commonly  not an operator.